# nServiceBus Beta Connection Closed Exception

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

Im trying to get an nServiceBus sample up and running across 2 pc's. I'be built the Distributor sample, added a couple of workers, which all work running locally.

If I add the command line parameter for either NServiceBus.Integration, or NServiceBus.Production  the master node delays and throws a .Net.WebException - "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
All firewalls are off but i dont even have to try putting anything on the other node, running locally causes the exception without changing anything other than the command line on the master.

Questions :

1. What's causing the sample throw?.. am i missing some configuration required to allow multiple physical PC's each hosting a logical subscriber?
2. Does specifying the integration or production profile mean you now need to specify a DB for the subs storage? will the default inmemory storage no longer work?(just for getting it up & running?)
3. Does the licence cover testing on multiple PC's using the other profiles?
4. Are there any samples, documentation or walkthroughs that do show configuration in a bit more depth, especially regarding creating distributed workers?

I've trawled the NServiceBus site, and read almost all the Stack overflow posts and still struggling to make this work!

Any help much appreciated!
Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its trying to connect to the raven db that should be on port 8080. In the beta you need to install raven manually. In the next drop raven will be autoinstalled for you

Comment: Many Thanks @Andreas, I've been pulling my hair out for 2 days! Maybe im a wee bit premature with the beta use :) I'm desperate to demo a solution to a problem which the nServiceBus 3 seems to fit perfectly!